# World History - Big Bang to TODAY

Tags: world

I am a very new World History enthusiast, pretty much a new kid on the block. Of late(the past few years), I have been having this sudden urge of understanding and learning everything that has happened with our UNIVERSE, from NOTHINGNESS to TODAY.

Yes, I have been able to find random pieces of information on the web, ranging from Big Bang to Ancient History to Modern History to Religion and it's role in History, the World Wars etc. However, I have not been able to connect the dots.

For example I have not been able to connect how life evolved after humans arrived on the planet, how did the things we do in our daily life start happening in the world, how did religion come into the picture, what were the other old religions like Hinduism and Buddhism doing when the Abrahamic religions and their events were unfolding, History of Israel and it's tryst with GOD, The World Wars, and the many many many glorious events that have happened on our planet.

I am not even sure if there is one-size-fits-all solution to my question. I would be extremely surprised and pleasantly satisfied and happy if I can find a single source of information. I would not mind approaching the answers from a religious perspective, as long as they keep me informed. However, since I am seeking information and not  religious elightenment , I would prefer things to be as much factual and informative as possible. I am saying this because I have come across some glowing sources of information, only to realize at the end that it had a biased religious flavour to it and ultimately guided towards the religion. No offence here to anyone, just a personal preference. I am sorry if I hurt any feelings by mentioning this.

All the highly learned and well-informed amazing people on this beautiful and humbling forum, I seek your help. Please redirect me to the right source to find the answers to my questions. I am okay with multiple books, as long as the dots are connected. I am okay with any professional course as well, if there exists one.

Many thanks, Jeet

Comment: Sadly, this is quite likely to get closed for being a list question, or for soliciting opinion or discussion. Our format here just doesn't work well for those. I think I have THE answer, but that's probably just hubris on my part. In the meantime I'd suggest checking out our help center for guidelines on how to ask questions.

Comment: "how life evolved after humans arrived on the planet" LOL, I guess we should be glad he didn't ask for all the history BEFORE us humans arrived on the planet.

Comment: The entirety of history is a tad broad. Why not start with a general reference (e.g., [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_world) or a [world history book](http://www.amazon.com/The-Human-Web-Birds-Eye-History/dp/0393925684)) and then ask here as you encounter specific questions that aren't well answered in the general reference (and there would be **many**).

Comment: Great to see a new light turned on. Your question is f-a-a-a-a-r t-o-o-o b-r-r-r-o-o-a-a-a-d for us to answer here. People write huge books to answer just small parts of your question. @Semaphore mentioned a couple of good sources, another is [New Scientist](http://www.newscientist.com/). While that may not sound like history, everything is connected, and their articles always give references that you can follow up. They cover *anything* that can be tackled in a scientific way, from, as you say, the Big Bang, to why do people believe in God, to archeology, to current science.

Comment: Also, probably only the last 10,000 years or so, out of about 14 billion since the big bang, are really the subject of history.  You'd need to go to paleontology, geology, astronomy, and probably particle physics to even approach an answer.

Comment: You might find the concept of [Big History interesting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_History) – a good place to look would be David Christian's [Maps of Time](https://books.google.com/books?id=7RdVmDjwTtQC)

Answer (score 1):

I know of only one resource that has close to the scope and detail you are looking for: Colin McEvedy's series of Penguin Atlases. I'd suggest starting with the one for Africa and the Near East Ancient History one.  You can then move up in time with the followup Near Eastern volumes and/or branch out in area with the North American and Pacific ones.

It probably sounds pretty daunting, but they are all relatively cheap paperbacks, and his writing style makes them real page-turners. I just wish he could have made volumes for India and South America before he died.

There are some other Atlases of World history floating around, but none are nearly as complete.